# How to zip two publishers if the second one depends on the values received by the first one?

Tags: swift, combine

The data that I need to create a model are split and only receivable via two API requests.

The first (`query.snapshotPublisher()`) publisher will get the main part of the model (inclusive it's ID) and the second request (`getPersonalLikeCount(blogModel: blogModel, userID: "408VYXScmxUtUQB91EoTf0LEMgj2")`) will get some additional data and needs the ID (which is part of the model that's why I'm passing the complete model) that I got from the first request.

If both requests would be independent I would use the `.Zip(other: )` operator but since the second one depends on the first one I tried the following to be able to pass the model to the second publisher.

But with this approach the second publisher get's cancelled after sending the first value and therefore won't update the model even when the `getPersonalLikeCount` publisher gets new data and should publish them again.

```
private func getBlogs(from query: Query) -> AnyPublisher<BlogModel, Error> {
    let publisher = query.snapshotPublisher()
        .flatMap { [self] blogModel -> AnyPublisher<(BlogModel, Int), Never> in
            let blogModelPublisher = Just(blogModel)
            let likeCountPublisher = getPersonalLikeCount(blogModel: blogModel, userID: "408VYXScmxUtUQB91EoTf0LEMgj2")
            let combined = Combine.Publishers.Zip(blogModelPublisher, likeCountPublisher)
            return combined.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        .map { blogModel, personalLikeCount -> BlogModel in
            var newModel = blogModel
            newModel.personalLikeCount = personalLikeCount
            return newModel
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    return publisher
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Semantically if you want to restart one request with a new one you use `map` followed by `switchToLatest`.  If and only if you want to do things in parallel  then you use `flatMap`.  Oddly enough Combine does not have a concatMap which is what you would use to do things serially in other reactive frameworks.  In your case its

1. Make the first request
2. Map into the second request
3. Map both values into a tuple
4. SwitchToLatest
5. Map the tuple into your result

```
doTheFirstThingPublisher
 .map { firstValue in 
   doTheSecondThingPubisher(with: firstValue)
     .map { secondValue in (firstValue, secondValue) }
 }
 .switchToLatest()
 .map { firstValue, secondValue in
   makeFinalValue(from: firstValue, and: secondValue)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when using this approach I only receive the first value sent by the first publisher and the other values get stuck before the first map operator. I should have mentioned that both publishers are repeating publishers.

Comment: Then change the first map and to a flatMap and remove the switch to latest. That will do a merge but merges are dangerous because you need to mind the upper limit on the number of subscriptions you may be creating.